# Как устранить ошибку phpMyAdmin #1932

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mac, xampp

Добрый день!

Установил последний `XAMPP` для `MAC OS`, `Apache` запускается без проблем, `MySQL` в том числе, однако как только в `phpMyAdmin` пытаюсь предпринять любую попытку что-либо создать, отредактировать или ипортировать, постоянно вылазит сообщение об ошибке с ответом от `MySQL:`

```
#1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine.
```

Отмечу, что никаких конфигурационных файлов я не трогал, установил программу и сразу столкнулся с этой проблемой!

Облазил всевозможные русскоязычные и англоязычные ресурсы в поисках ответа, но ни одного более ли менее конструктивного ответа не нашел! В основном все ответы крутятся вокруг ошибки `#1146`, но это ошибка другого рода.

Answer (score 1):

phpMyAdmin может работать в двух режимах: с собственной базой данных, где хранятся настройки и история запросов и без такой базы данных. Судя по всему у вас phpMyAdmin настроен таким образом, что он ожидает увидеть базу данных приложения phpmyadmin. А ее либо нет, либо в ней нет таблицы `pma__tracking`.

В первую очередь посмотрите список баз данных, есть ли там база данных `phpmyadmin`, если база данных имеется, проверьте имеется ли в ней таблица `pma__tracking`.

Если базы данных не существует, найдите место установки phpMyAdmin, проверьте есть ли там папка sql, а в ней файл create_tables.sql. Если файл в наличие, создайте базу данных `phpmyadmin` и разверните туда содержимое дампа create_tables.sql. Если у вас отсутствует лишь таблица `pma__tracking`, найдите в дампе оператор `CREATE TABLE` для этой таблицы и выполните его.

Если по прежнему ничего не работает, найдите в папке установки phpMyAdmin конфигурационный файл config.inc.php. В нем найдите следующие строки

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
...
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
```

Как вариант, просто закомментируйте их, чтобы работать в режиме без базы данных. Если база данных необходима, проверьте MySQL-пользователя в директивах

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
```

Он должен существовать, иметь корректный пароль и иметь доступ к базе данных `phpmyadmin`.